# Codeigniter Zip Library how to zip existent file

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, zip

Im moving un-zipped files to a server directory  /zip/file.unzipped.png

now i need to take that file and zip it.

Is it possible to do that or a need the zip archive as codeigniter guide says?

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Is what you're looking for just a straight download, and not saving the archive on disk before download?

If this is the case you can do what @zer02 suggested, but remove the archive step.

> $name = 'mydata1.txt';
>
> $data = 'A Data String!';
>
> $this->zip->add_data($name, $data);
>
> <del>// Write the zip file to a folder on your server. Name it "my_backup.zip"</del>
>
> <del>$this->zip->archive('/path/to/directory/my_backup.zip');</del>
>
> // Download the file to your desktop. Name it "my_backup.zip"
>
> $this->zip->download('my_backup.zip');

The zip library should gather up all the data you've added to the zip cache in memory, and create a file to download dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the user manual: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/zip.html

There are two functions that jump out me for your use case:

`$this->zip->read_file()`

> Permits you to compress a file that already exists somewhere on your
>   server. Supply a file path and the zip class will read it and add it
>   to the archive:

`$this->zip->read_dir()`

> Permits you to compress a folder (and its contents) that already
>   exists somewhere on your server. Supply a file path to the directory
>   and the zip class will recursively read it and recreate it as a Zip
>   archive. All files contained within the supplied path will be encoded,
>   as will any sub-folders contained within it.

Comment: same story, i would like to use NOT a zip archive.

Comment: Your question says you want to zip the file, but now you say you don't want to zip the file. Could you please clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: the ci guide talks about a .zip archive where to store all files, maybe my english so bad, but that is what i don't need, i just need to zip files without any zip archive on server

Comment: A zip archive is the same thing as a zip file. What do you want to happen once the files are zipped? Should it be served to a user as a download, but not stored on the server?

Answer (score -1):

```
$name = 'mydata1.txt';

$data = 'A Data String!';

$this->zip->add_data($name, $data);
```

// Write the zip file to a folder on your server. Name it "my_backup.zip"

```
$this->zip->archive('/path/to/directory/my_backup.zip');
```

// Download the file to your desktop. Name it "my_backup.zip"

```
$this->zip->download('my_backup.zip');
```

[Zip Lib CI](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/zip.html)

Comment: hi, i don't need to use a .zip archive, i have existent files on my server, i just need to zip them nothing more, it is possible?

Comment: Don't use $this->zip->archive as that will write the archive to the disk. I think the OP just wants to zip the existing files and download the zip, without writing the zip to disk first.